# Can a ring $R$ be finitely-generated as a $k$-algebra under one map but not under another

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

We say that an extension of rings $R \to S$ (the map is a ring homomorphism and so takes $1 \to 1$) is finitely-generated as an $R$-algebra if the image of $R$ is contained in the center of $S$ and every element of $S$ can be written as a polynomial with coefficients in the image of $R$ whose variables are from a finite set of the elements of $S$.

Given two extensions $\phi_1 : k \to S$ and $\phi_2 : k \to S$, where $k$ is a field. Is it possible for $\phi_1$ to be a finitely-generated $k$-algebra, but $\phi_2$ to not be a finitely-generated $k$-algebra? I don't see a reason why this can't happen, but I can't find an example.

Bonus points if you know the answer when $k$ is not assumed to be a field, where I feel more confident that this can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field, $k=S=K(x_1,x_2,...)$ (the field of fractions of $K[x_1,x_2,...]$, the polynomial ring in countably infinitely many variables over $K$), $\phi_1:k\to S$ be the identity $\mathrm{id}_k$, and $\phi_2:k\to S$ be given by fixing $K$ and mapping $x_i$ to $x_{2i}$ for all whole $i\geq 1$.

Evidently $\phi_1$ makes $S$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Furhter, adjoining any finite amount of elements of $S$ to the image of $\phi_2$ will not suffice to adjoin all of the missing $x_{2k+1}$s for all natural $k$, which suffices an argument for that $\phi_2$ doesn't make $S$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

For an example where $k$ is not a field replace in the above $k=S=K[x_1,x_2,...]$. For more examples taking appropriately "small" extensions of $S$ allows to consider when e.g. $k$ is a field but $S$ isn't.

Note also that in the above that if $k$ is took to be a field, the degree of $k$ over its prime field is necessarily infinite: If a ring $S$ can be regarded as a finitely generated $k$-algebra for $k$ a finite field or number field, then any way of making $S$ a $k$-algebra will have it finitely generated. This can be seen from the fact that for a finite field extension $K\subseteq L$ an $L$-algebra is finitely generated if and only if it is when canonically regarded as a $K$-algebra.

It would seem plausible that for an example over $k$ to exist $k$ also would necessarily have to have infinite transcendence degree over its prime field, however I'm unsure how one'd go about proving that.